# looking for spark scala(java) code for date string with spaces in between with specific conditions

Tags: scala, date

need some suggestions on below requirement.
Each response help a lot thanks in advance....

I have a date of type String  with timestamp ex: `Jan  8 2019  4:44 AM`

My requirement is if the date is single digit I want date to be 1 space and digit
(ex: 8) and if the date is 2 digits which is dates from 10 to 31 I want date with no space(ex:10) and also same for hour in timestamp.

to summarize: if the date is 1 to 9 and hour in timestamp is 1 to 9 looking for below string

```
Jan  8 2019  4:44 AM
```

if the date is 10 to 31 and hour in timestamp is 10 to 12 looking for below string

```
Jan 18 2019 12:44 AM
```

right now I am creating a date in following way:

```
val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM  d yyyy  h:mm a")
```

but the above format satisfies only one condition which is dates from 1 to 9.

my application is spark with scala so looking for some spark scala code or java.

I appreciate your help...

Thanks..

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use for example `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

Use `p` as a pad modifier in the format pattern string. In Java syntax (sorry):

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "MMM ppd ppppu pph:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.of(2019, Month.JANUARY, 8, 4, 44)
            .format(formatter));
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.of(2019, Month.JANUARY, 18, 0, 44)
            .format(formatter));
```

> ```
> Jan  8 2019  4:44 AM
> Jan 18 2019 12:44 AM
> ```

And do yourself the favour: Forget everything about the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is notoriously troublesome and fortunately long outdated. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

To quote the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class documentation:

> **Pad modifier:** Modifies the pattern that immediately follows to be padded with spaces. The pad width is determined by the number of pattern letters. This is the same as calling [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.padNext(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#padNext-int-).
>
> For example, 'ppH' outputs the hour-of-day padded on the left with spaces to a width of 2.